# How to update multiple TextView every X seconds and X time using "for loop" or "if and else if" method?

Tags: android, time, textview

I am trying to display heart rate taken from Microsoft Band for example every 20 seconds for 6 times. In this case I create 6 Text View and I will take the reading from the band and display it on the 6 Text View. However how do I display all 6 readings on 6 Text View? So far I can only display one reading on the first text view only. Any idea how to use may for loop or if else to display the other 5 readings every 20 seconds?

My code which take the heart rate reading and convert it to string:

```
public void onHeartrateClick(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.Bhistory){

        TextView e = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtHeart);
        String string = e.getText().toString();

        Intent i = new Intent(Pulse.this, History.class);
        i.putExtra("History", string);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

My code in the history.xml which display the readings:

```
public class History extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    String history = getIntent().getStringExtra("History");

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVhistory);
    textView.setText(history);
}
```

My History.xml picture which displays the reading taken from the band:

[image]

Hope to get help soon as I am doing this for a project. Thank you :)

Comment: are your 'readings' a list of Strings ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code in your activity onCreate().

```
public class History extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    String history = getIntent().getStringExtra("History");

    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVhistory);
    mTextView .setText(history);

    Handler handler=new Handler();

    final Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //put your textview update code here
            mTextView .setText(history);
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);//reschedule this runnable
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just want to ask something with regards to the textview update code.

For the code, I have to write several textview code? Example:

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVhistory);
    textView.setText(history);

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(history);

And so on?

Or should it be:


TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(history);

Sorry kind of new to programming so have to ask so much questions..

Comment: Hope to get your reply soon.

Comment: Ideally we create a field in activity class  to refer  each textview...generally we don't use the same name for different textviews in code

Comment: If I edit my code into the below one can?         public void run() {

                //put your textview update code here
                String history = getIntent().getStringExtra("History");

                TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVhistory);
                textView1.setText(history);

                TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVhistory2);
                textView2.setText(history);
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000);//reschedule this runnable
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

Comment: Sorry I do not understand as I am new.. just started learning java and android few days ago. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: M outside. .will post the code 2mrw. .In the meanwhile you can refer an android sample code

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. I've used your code however once the Bhistory button is pressed, it straight away display the reading even though i changed the timing to 10000. And it only display on the first text view while the others textview did not change it remained as 'New Text'.